Customize Spring Boot Annotation With New Fields
I want to customize spring-boot Cacheable annotation with new fields. Is it possible?
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Reflective
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "new-cache")
public @interface DemoCacheable {

    String prefix() default "demo-java-cache:";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, value = "cacheNames")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, value = "value")
    String[] cacheNames() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class)
    String key() default "";
}

I need to create DemoCacheable key as prefix + key prefix might be constant but my need is new-key will be prefix + key at the end of it. Is it possbile?
So when I define it like:
@DemoCacheable(key = "abc") -> it should be @Cachebale(cacheNames = "new-cache", key = "demo-java-cache:abc")
